# Flutter: Can't and border radius to the bottom of container items in silver grid view

Tags: flutter, dart

At first i have a container with padding and margin which includes the child Grid Widget..

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 150.0,
      child: QuickStatGrid(),
    );
  }
```

[image: GRID VIEW]

In QuickStatGrid, i have the grid view builder with both cross-axiscount and itemcount 4... which render child blur colored container QuickStatGrid...

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return GridView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 4,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
          childAspectRatio: 1
          ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => QuickStatCard()
      );
  }
```

In QuickStatCard i have a simple blue colored container with border radius set to all 10.0 but radius on the bottom two side doesn't add

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10)
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BorderRadius.all` is actually working on all edges, you're simply not able to see it here.

As you specified the `childAspectRatio` to `1` in `QuickStatGrid`, the blue `Container` has a square shape. But as you can see, it has not enough space to be fully visible.

You could try :

- improving the `height` of the black `Container` if you want the blue ones to keep their size
- improving the `childAspectRatio` (i.e. to 1.5) if you want the black one to keep its size, but blue containers'll now have a rectangle shape
- playing with the `crossAxisSpacing` in `QuickStatGrid` if you want the black one to keep its size and have blue containers fully visible with a square shape

Comment: thanks @Larvouu, improved it by icreasing the black container height